# Why do I get a different 'class' file after changing only symbol names?

Tags: java, version-control, bytecode

Why does the Java byte-code interpreter change a 'class' file when I change only symbol names (classes, interfaces, functions or variables) in the corresponding 'java' file?

I am maintaining both types under source control (GIT), and I keep seeing "twice the amount of changed files" even for cosmetic changes such as the one mentioned above.

BTW, the question is **not** on source-control issues, but just FYI, the reason I keep these files on GIT is in order to be able to do "clean up" (delete all unversioned files), and then run the program from a command-line without recompiling it.

If you have any idea how to achieve this functionality (run without build) otherwise, then I would be happy to hear it...

Thanks

Comment: You should not store `.class` files in git.

Comment: Thank you SLaks. In general I would agree on that one, and I will get rid of them at some point, but it's not really the question at hand.

Comment: Why wouldn't changing the symbol names change the class file?

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: To the best of my knowledge, in native languages such as C and C++, where the executable runs on the "real machine" (in oppose to Java, where the executable runs on a virtual machine) - changing symbol names does not affect the executable (unless it contains debug information, and I'm not even sure about that). I guess that my expectation from the Java byte-code interpreter to do the same was wrong...

Comment: @barakmanos changing the symbols does affect the binary produced even in C and C++ as you may have debug information or have a module which will be bound by the linker later.  If you dump `strings a.out` you can see many calls to method names for example.

Comment: Great, so that answers your question ("Why **wouldn't** changing the symbol names change the class file"), but it doesn't answer mine ("Why **would** changing the symbol names change the class file").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JVM needs access to the symbol names, for a number of reasons, including the following.

- The JVM uses symbol names to find classes, methods and so on.
- The presence of symbol names enables us to write code that uses reflection.
- Symbol names appear in stack traces when an exception is thrown.

So the symbol names need to be stored in the class path.

Answer (score 7):

Because the class files contain the symbol names.

Generally, people do not keep their class files in source control. If someone wants an old version of a class file, they get the old source file and compile it.

Comment: Please see my additional note on the source-control issue (although it was not the main purpose of the question, but everyone appears to be addressing that as well). Other than that, thank you for the quick explanation.